# Comparing images for pixel similarity

Tags: java, image, comparison

I need to compare the pixels in two similar images, createing a saved third image where the pixels that are the same between the two are turned blue. The code also needs to check that the images are of the same size before beginning the comparison, and exits with an error to the console if they are not the same size. 
Here is the code i have. i still need to overlay the two images and turn the similar pixels blue.
 I need to use Filechooser.pickAFile but other than that i a completely lost as to how to go about it.

```js
// Karl Thomas
// kthoma34
// Mon @ 4:00

import java.awt.Color;

public class PP2kthoma34 
{
  
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    // Original picture
    Picture p1;            // create the variable
    String fileName = FileChooser.pickAFile();
    FileChooser.setMediaPath ( fileName );
    System.out.println (fileName);
    p1 = new Picture( fileName );
    
    // Width and length of original picture
    int width1 = p1.getWidth();
    int height1 = p1.getHeight();
    Pixel[] pixelArray1 = p1.getPixels();
    System.out.println(pixelArray1.length + "pixels");
    System.out.println("");
    
    
    
    // Modified picture
    Picture p2;            // create the variable
    String filename2;
    filename2 = FileChooser.pickAFile();
    FileChooser.setMediaPath ( filename2 );
    System.out.println (filename2);
    p2 = new Picture( filename2 );
    
    //Width and Height of manipulated picture
    int width2 = p2.getWidth();
    int height2 = p2.getHeight();
    Pixel[] pixelArray2 = p2.getPixels();
    System.out.println(pixelArray2.length + "pixels");
    System.out.println("");
    
    //checking that the images are the same size
    if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) 
     {
      System.err.println("Error: Image dimensions do not match");
      System.exit(1);
     }
    
    // Save Third image with similarities highlighted in blue.
    String filename3;
    filename3 = FileChooser.pickAFile();
    p2.write( filename3 );
  }

}// end
```

Comment: [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: It's a start (you need to get the image pixel data somehow).  I'd recommend having a quick Google and see what "java image difference" brings up

Comment: I really do not see what this does to help me? and I have, for about a week now, and none of it is what I have been looking. I have two images, they are very similar but on has been altered in slight ways. I need to compare the similar pixels between the two and highlight them blue. i need to use FileChooser.pickAFile to get the two images, and to save the third output one. i also need to prove they are the same width and height. Using java. I do not know how to do this. No one is helping.

Comment: Okay, so you need the pixel data, BufferedImage gives you access to the pixel data in a common format that relieves you from the underlying image format. However, if you can't see how it helps then just ignore it. The top four or do links I got from Google looked pretty promising to me